# To display image using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

In the code below I have an image in C Directory and I want to display the image on window load using JavaScript. I tried but image is not displaying.

```
<div id="thmbDiv"></div>
```

*Script:*

```
window.onload=function() {
    var thumbContainer = document.getElementById("thmbDiv");
    var thumbnail = document.createElement("img");
    thumbnail.onload=function() {
        thumbContainer.appendChild(thumbnail);
    }
    thumbnail.src = "C:\Hello\Search\Image0529.jpg";
}
```

Comment: You need to use the `file:` protocol (this would look like `file://C:/Hello/Search/Image0529.jpg` if I'm not mistaken), and you need to load the webpage using the `file:` protocol as well.

Comment: @zneak If he is working from a Javascript context that will allow him to access local files, that is likely the format it uses (OP has not specified environment). If he is working with Javascript in modern browsers, he will not be able to access the local file system..

Comment: @mattsven, I know. That's why I said that the webpage, too, had to be loaded with the `file:` protocol.

Comment: @zneak Just clarifying. I read that in your original comment but it didn't fully register, I don't think.

Comment: @zneak  i tried but it is not displaying

Comment: Look up the `file:` protocol structure on Windows, I'm on Mac OS right now and we don't have lettered drives so I can't test for you. It's probably just a Google search away.

Comment: Backslash "\" is an escape character. Try using `C:\\Hello\\Search\\Image0529.jpg` instead.

Comment: @zneak I think it's suppose to have 3 forward slashes at the beginning `file:///C:/Hello/Search/Image0529.jpg`, instead of just 2.

Comment: You don't have to use file:/// as some are saying (JS does this for you), but you have to use FORWARD slashes, not backwards slashes in the file name (like @imtheman stated a bit unclearly)

Comment: It is working fine.But, you should give absolute path with forward slashes "C://Hello/Search/Image0529.jpg"

Comment: @pewpew Yes, I agree, it is preferred to use forward slashes. However, you can use backslashes if you escape them first.

Comment: @imtheman That is true, but it still looks cleaner using forwards as you need half as many slashes.

Comment: @pewpew Absolutely, forward slashs are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<div id="thmbDiv"><img id="imageTag" src=""></div>

window.onload=function() {
 var thumbnail = document.getElementById("imageTag");
 thumbnail.src="C:\Hello\Search\Image0529.jpg";
}
```